# 64 bit MapViewOfFile slowness?

Tags: windows, performance, 64-bit, memory-mapped-files

We've got a bit of an issue here regarding 64 bit performance issues in MapViewOfFile over large volumes (hundreds of GB);

Under 32 bit our app mapped thousands and thousands of views of 64 Kb in size, continuously swapping at will over the database.
Under 64 bit, the entire database can finally be mapped into our process' virtual address space.
So far so good.

One would expect the 64 bit version to perform much better than the 32 bit version, as we let Windows handle all the swapping (if any is needed, that is, presumably this mostly depends on the amount of physical memory present in the server).

In practise however, the 64 bit version (mapping all files into memory at once) performs much worse, taking between 2 and 40 times the amount of time the 32 bit version took to work it's way through the database.

We eliminated a lot of factors, and it really seems to caused by the Common Cache of Windows itself. (We're mostly but not exclusively using Windows Server 2008 - it's the same problem all across the board though.)

Is there anything we can do to gain the additional speedup you'd expect when mapping large files into memory just once? (As opposed to continuously mapping & swapping small chunks manually.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simple code for example?

Comment: I have the same issue, and found the same problem.  I ran RamMap from sysinternals and found that a 32-bit process used ~4Gb of Mapped memory, and this was also reflected in the Standby List.  RamMap also allows these tables to be cleared so the file system cache effects can be eliminated.  The same program compiled under win64 results in a ~12Gb Mapped size.  I am mapping a small view of the file and remapping it, so I'm not getting a view of the entire file (~15Gb).  If you find anything out about this, please let me know.  Thanks, Dennis

Comment: Any solution or mitigation to this issue? Please share if any.